# ¿Es posible lanzar una notificación cuando el usuario no ha abierto la app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, android-notifications

Necesito que mi app lance una notificación sin la necesidad de ser abierta. Es decir, que al encenderse el móvil la Activity se ejecute en segundo plano. Hasta ahora he conseguido que lance una notificación así:

```
private void pushNotification(){

        int NOTIFICATION_ID = 234;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            CharSequence name = "my_channel";
            String Description = "This is my channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(Description);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mChannel.setShowBadge(false);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());



    }
```

Pero solo se ejecuta cuando la app entra en el método OnCreate(), desde donde se llama la función pushNotification()

Si puedo añadir algo a la pregunta para aclararla, no duden en comentarlo.
Michas gracias

Comment: Yo lo hago con firebase de Google y solo es necesario que se ejecute una vez la App, luego aunque no se esté ejecutando llegan, lo que no se si se reinicia el móvil creo que se tendría que iniciar la App aunque sea una sola vez.
Aquí hay un manual sobre como hacerlo. http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/notificaciones-push-android-firebase-cloud-messaging-1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto puede realizarse mediante [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

El método `onMessageReceived()` de tu clase que implementa `FirebaseMessagingService` en tu proyecto, es la que recibe la notificación y puede ser mostrada aún sin abrir la aplicación.

```
public class FCMListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification received: " + message);
        ...
        ...
    }

}
```

Revisa : [Notificaciones Push en Android: Firebase Cloud Messaging](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/notificaciones-push-android-firebase-cloud-messaging-1/)

Answer (score 1):

Es Depende de lo que necesites para tu proyecto. pero principalmente es que necesite:

- "Service class" : realizar alguna tarea en el fondo mientras no se    utiliza la aplicación.
- "BroadcastReceiver" :  mostrar la notificación com tu quieras cuando obtenga la    información requerida de "Service Class".

***Aquí hay un ejemplo de BroadcastReceiver para mostrar una notificación cuando recibe un SMS. Aquí no he creado una clase de Service porque no es necesario. Ya está creado por android. y puedo obtener los SMS.***

**primero crear una clase extiende BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class pullData extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            // notification received
            Log.d("result"  , "received");
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Received")
                    .setContentText("Received Successfully")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

**luego en AndroidManifest.xml add this line `<receiver android:name=".pullData" android:enabled="true"><intent-filter android:priority="2147483647"><action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /></intent-filter></receiver>`

como asi :**

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.elmaravilla.stackoverflowtest">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>


<receiver android:name=".pullData" android:enabled="true">
                <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>    

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**y en MainActivity.java necesitas pedir permiso para leer SMS:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        requestPermissions(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS);


    }
    private void requestPermissions(String permission, int requestCode) {
        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Granting permission is necessary!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{permission},
                        requestCode);

                // requestCode is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.



                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
}
```

**Asi puedes enviar notificación al usuario cuando reciba sms.**

**Espero que lo entiendas bien.**